# iFrame shows no scrollbars

Tags: 2013, javascript, iframe

I have a simple iFrame within a content editor where I want to add SP content (dynamically via JS):
This is working fine...

```
<iframe id="VersionHistoryFrame" src="http://www.test.de" width="400" height="400" name="Version History" scrolling="yes" style="overflow:visible;"></iframe>
```

But if I add some SharePoint content it doesn't show the scrollbars:

```
<iframe id="VersionHistoryFrame" src="/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list={B13FE613-DA65-4AB1-BXCD-E32FD25820C4}&ID=99&IsDlg=1" width="400" height="400" name="Version History" scrolling="yes" style="overflow:visible;"></iframe>
```

I'm not expert in HTML/CSS, but I tried several paramters for scrollbars (with/without css)... Nothing seems to be working.
thx

Answer (score 0):

Use this css to enable the scrollbars:

`iframe {
    overflow: scroll;
}`

Answer (score -1):

`scrolling` property is not supported in HTML5. Try removing that all together.